# "vagrant up" fails with "NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED" error

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, vagrant

I am following the basic "Getting Started" guide: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html

I ran `vagrant init <etc>` followed by `vagrant up`, but it fails with "NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED" error.

Then by enabling debug logging with `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up`, I get the following error output:

```
ERROR vagrant: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:316:in `execute'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_4_2.rb:165:in `import'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:15:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box_url.rb:72:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in `action'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 INFO interface: error: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/Users/me/.vagrant.d/boxes/precise32/virtualbox/box.ovf"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/me/.vagrant.d/boxes/precise32/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress object failure: NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED
```

My system setup info:

Vagrant 1.2.2

VirtualBox 4.2.14 (Also tried 4.2.10, same error)

Mac OSX 10.8.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a regression in version VirtualBox 4.2.14, and a fix has been checked into version control.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11895

Until the fix is released, downgrading VirtualBox is your best option. Version 4.2.12 has been reported to work.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation as to what the actual problem was? While this may be true it doesn't really help us understand what the problem is so we can fix it.

Comment: Oddly enough, this did the trick. Neither 4.2.10 nor 4.2.14 worked, but 4.2. **12**, now that's the ticket.

Comment: its seems to be working in 4.2.16 as well

Answer (score 0):

The following may be of some help:

http://www.rkoster.net/2011/02/17/virtualbox-code-ns_error_call_failed-0x800706be/

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1622

> For best results, quit all VirtualBox UIs, halt all VirtualBox VMs,
>   and only use Vagrant + VirtualBox from a single user.

or...

> It came down to the fact that I was running from an elevated prompt
>   (Administrator.)

Do you have any strange setup, like multiple users, or the GUI open, or a user with restricted access or non-standard folders or tight permissions?